# class/type columns and match factor levels of dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-caret, categorical-data, scoring

I need to score a big dataframe-- 250M rows x ~2000 cols (1TB).  A fit has been developed (from C5.0 library) based on training data.  Currently the entire dataset wont fit in memory.  Big data solutions are being investigated, but I'm wondering if I can cut up the file and run predict() in chunks.

The basic problem is that I want to translate column classes and factor levels from one dataframe to another. More detail:

PROBLEM #1: Some of the column classes don't match when being read from hadoop.

PROBLEM #2: by chunking you can get factors that have fewer factor levels than the training dataset (since you're looking at a subsample of the full set).  Because of this predict() doesn't want to try and score a set that has missing factor levels.

QUESTION:  I was hoping to just take the classes and factor levels from the training set and class the columns and 'relevel' the factors in the big scoring set with levels().  Can one take classes of columns and factors of one dataframe and transpose them to the same variable name to 'relevel' the variables of another dataframe?   I suppose this could be done with a for loop by reading factors from one frame and applying it to the other.  But this would require lots of if statements for all the classes, it seems it would be messy.  Is there a way to do this with apply functions or a simpler 'one-liner'?

Comment: you can use training levels for chunk using `chunk$var <-
 factor(chunk$var, levels(train$var))`

Comment: Yes but I have to do this for 1800 variables.  Not the easiest of solutions.

Comment: `mapply(function(chunkfield, trainfield) factor(chunkfield, levels(trainfield)), chunk, train)`